# Using animate tp update a progress bar smoothly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I am using an API that passes a numeric percentage as it is loading. Currently I am using jQuery's css method to update the width of the progress bar as it is loading. This works well but the width updates every half second or so it is jerky.

```
NEEDATA.onScriptEvent('progress', function(percentage, status, filename){
       var progressStatus = percentage;
       var round = Math.round(progressStatus.percentage * 100) / 100;

// here is the part that needs some work

       $("#percentage div").css({
       'width' : round + '%'
       });
});
```

I would like to animate it smoothly with easing. I have tried using animate instead of css but it was very jerky. The percentages arent passed that quickly, so the animate is not smooth.

```
   $("#percentage div").animate({
       'width' : round + '%'
   }, 100);
```

I am trying to figure out a better way of smoothly animating this progress bar as percentage data is being passed to it, compensating for the fairly slow interval at which data is being passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var div = $('#percentage div');
if(!div.is(':animated')){
   div.animate({
       'width' : round + '%'
   }, 100);
}
```

Comment: It is definitely improved, but I suppose I am looking for more of an easing solution so it doesn't halt to a stop.